# Почему g++ и msvc по-разному интерпретируют код?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

Дан код:

```
int main() {
    int a = 8;
    int b = 100;
    float d;
    int c = ++a * a++;
    d = b / (--a);
    return 0;
}
```

но почему-то в [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) переменная `с` равна `90`, а в [msvc](/questions/tagged/msvc) она равна `81`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Неопределенное поведение классическое:

```
 int c = ++a * a++;
```

**Для C++98:**

Двухкратная запись в переменную `a` в пределах одной точки следования.

**Для C++11:**

Нарушение [правил](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) порядка вычисления.

Программа ошибочна. Компилятор может реагировать случайным образом.